# Finding the number of of nodes and gpus of DistributedDataParallel

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, distributed-computing, ddp

I would like to know what number should I select for nodes and gpus.  
I use Tesla V100-SXM2 (8 boards).

I tried: 
nodes = 1, gpus=1 (only the first gpu works) 
nodes=1, gpus =8 (It took very long time and cannot execute)

Did I got wrong parameter for the nodes and gpus? or Is my code wrong ? I would appreciate if you could help me out. The code below is simplified sample code of DPP.

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--nodes', default=1, type=int, metavar='N')
    parser.add_argument('-g', '--gpus', default=1, type=int,
                        help='number of gpus per node')
    parser.add_argument('-nr', '--nr', default=0, type=int,
                        help='ranking within the nodes')
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', default=200, type=int, metavar='N',
                        help='number of total epochs to run')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    args.world_size = args.gpus * args.nodes
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = 'host1'
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '7777'
    mp.spawn(train, nprocs=args.gpus, args=(args,))


def train(gpu, args):
    rank = args.nr * args.gpus + gpu
    dist.init_process_group(
        backend='nccl',
        init_method='env://',
        world_size=args.world_size,
        rank=rank
    )

    torch.manual_seed(0)
    model = ConvNet()
    torch.cuda.set_device(gpu)
    model.cuda(gpu)
    batch_size = 100
    # define loss function (criterion) and optimizer
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().cuda(gpu)
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), 1e-4)

    # Wrapper around our model to handle parallel training
    model = nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(model, device_ids=[gpu])

    # Data loading code
    train_dataset = get_datasets()
    
    # Sampler that takes care of the distribution of the batches such that
    # the data is not repeated in the iteration and sampled accordingly
    train_sampler = torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler(
        train_dataset,
        num_replicas=args.world_size,
        rank=rank
    )
    
    # We pass in the train_sampler which can be used by the DataLoader
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset,
                                               batch_size=batch_size,
                                               shuffle=False,
                                               num_workers=0,
                                               pin_memory=True,
                                               sampler=train_sampler)

    start = datetime.now()
    total_step = len(train_loader)
    for epoch in range(args.epochs):
        for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
            images = images.cuda(non_blocking=True)
            labels = labels.cuda(non_blocking=True)
            # Forward pass
            outputs = model(images)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

            # Backward and optimize
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            if (i + 1) % 100 == 0 and gpu == 0:
                print('Epoch [{}/{}], Step [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}'.format(
                    epoch + 1, 
                    args.epochs, 
                    i + 1, 
                    total_step,
                    loss.item())
                   )
    if gpu == 0:
        print("Training complete)
```